# SQL - How to retrieve 5 most recent comments for each user

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table called '**user_text**'

```
| id | user_id |        date         |         text         |
|----|---------|---------------------|----------------------|
| 1  |    4    | 07/01/2019 10:04:11 | This is a test       |
| 2  |    9    | 19/11/2018 09:43:00 | Here's another test  |
| ...|         |                     |                      |
```

What I need to do is to select the 5 most recent (field 'date') entries for each user_id

I've searched a lot about it and it seems that somehow I need a subquery but I can't find the right combination.

Comment: which version of mysql ?

Comment: It is version 5.*

Comment: I tried a lot of things, trust me... but nothing makes sence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 5.x, one option uses a correlated subquery:

```
select u.*
from user_text u
where (
    select count(*)
    from user_text u1
    where u1.user_id = u.user_id and u1.date >= u.date
) <= 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 5;
```